# How to correctly protect API in STS Asp.Net 2.2 project + Api Asp.Net 2.2 project + angular7 client

Tags: identityserver4

Have been struggling with this for a while, no problem having angular7 client access id4 Asp.Net core 2.2 project for logging in and getting jwt back, struggling with angular7 client accessing Asp.Net core 2.2 api project protected api which is under id4 protection.

jwt.io decode (values x'd out):

```
HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE


{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "c672fc19f3ff652c5c8816cfac31bfcc",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
PAYLOAD:DATA


{
  "nbf": 1550161736,
  "exp": 1550164736,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44340",
  "aud": "angularclient",
  "nonce": "N0.88924643059608991550161727071",
  "iat": 1550161736,
  "at_hash": "A3fYyAynZIUQN5Z3ugvpvw",
  "sid": "90c459301964e9f136a38b9b19d9b1e0",
  "sub": "71765055-647D-432E-AFB6-0F84218D0247",
  "auth_time": 1550161731,
  "idp": "local",
  "preferred_username": "xxxxxxxx",
  "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "regid": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "jseg": "xxxxx",
  "jobid": "xxxxx",
  "role": "xxxx",
  "given_name": "xxxx",
  "family_name": "Grexxxxenwald",
  "email": "xxxxx",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

ID4 config:

```
private static readonly string[] customClaimTypes = { "role", "jseg", "jobid", "regid", "api1" };

        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResource("api1scope", customClaimTypes),
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
        {
            return new ApiResource[]
            {
                new ApiResource()
                {
                    Name = "api1",
                    Description = "tsicApis",
                    ApiSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret(Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:STSTSICApisSecuredSecret").Value.Sha256())
                    },
                    Scopes =
                    {
                        new Scope()
                        {
                            Name = "api1",
                            DisplayName = "Scope for the api1 ApiResource",
                        },
                    },
                    UserClaims = customClaimTypes
                }
            };
        }

        // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            var trustedClientSecrets = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:TrustedClientSecrets").Value;

            var angularClientUrl = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:AngularClientUrl").Value;
            var angularRedirectUris = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:AngularRedirectUris").Value;
            var angularPostLogoutRedirectUris = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:AngularPostLogoutRedirectUris").Value;
            var angularAllowedCorsOrigins = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:AngularAllowedCorsOrigins").Value;
            var angularClientSecret = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:STSTSICApisSecuredSecret").Value;

            var mvcClientSecrets = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:MVCClientSecrets").Value;
            var mvcRedirectUris = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:MVCRedirectUris").Value;
            var mvcFrontChannelLogoutUri = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:MVCFrontChannelLogoutUri").Value;
            var mvcPostLogoutRedirectUris = Startup.Configuration.GetSection("StsConfig:MVCPostLogoutRedirectUris").Value;


            // client credentials client
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "angularclient",
                    ClientId = "angularclient",
                    RequireClientSecret = true,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret(angularClientSecret) },

                    RequireConsent = true,
                    AllowRememberConsent = false,

                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 33000,// 330 seconds, default 60 minutes
                    IdentityTokenLifetime = 3000,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = angularAllowedCorsOrigins.Split(','),
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "openid",
                        "profile",
                        "email",
                        "role",
                        "jseg",
                        "jobid",
                        "regid",
                        "api1",
                        "api1scope",
                    },

                    RedirectUris = angularRedirectUris.Split(','),
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = angularPostLogoutRedirectUris.Split(',')
                },
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvcclient",
                    ClientName = "mvcclient",

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret(mvcClientSecrets.Sha256()) },

                    RequireConsent = true,
                    AllowRememberConsent = false,

                    RedirectUris = mvcRedirectUris.Split(','),
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = mvcFrontChannelLogoutUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = mvcPostLogoutRedirectUris.Split(','),

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "openid",
                        "profile",
                        "api1"
                    }
                },

            };
        }
```

Angular app.module.ts:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService
  ) {
    const openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration = new OpenIDImplicitFlowConfiguration();

    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.storage = sessionStorage;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.stsServer = environment.oidc.stsServer;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.redirect_url = environment.oidc.redirect_url;
    // The Client MUST validate that the aud (audience) Claim contains its client_id value registered at the Issuer
    // identified by the iss (issuer) Claim as an audience.
    // The ID Token MUST be rejected if the ID Token does not list the Client as a valid audience,
    // or if it contains additional audiences not trusted by the Client.
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.client_id = 'angularclient';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.response_type = 'id_token token';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.scope = 'openid profile email api1scope';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.post_logout_redirect_uri = environment.oidc.post_logout_redirect_uri;
    // openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.start_checksession = this.oidcConfigService.clientConfiguration.start_checksession;

    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.silent_renew = true;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.silent_renew_url = environment.oidc.silent_renew_url;

    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.post_login_route = environment.oidc.post_login_route;
    // HTTP 403
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.forbidden_route = '/forbidden';
    // HTTP 401
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.unauthorized_route = '/unauthorized';
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.log_console_warning_active = environment.oidc.log_console_warning_active;
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.log_console_debug_active = environment.oidc.log_console_debug_active;
    // id_token C8: The iat Claim can be used to reject tokens that were issued too far away from the current time,
    // limiting the amount of time that nonces need to be stored to prevent attacks.The acceptable range is Client specific.
    openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds = environment.oidc.max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds;

    // openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.iss_validation_off = false;
    // configuration.FileServer = this.oidcConfigService.clientConfiguration.apiFileServer;
    // configuration.Server = this.oidcConfigService.clientConfiguration.apiServer;

    const authWellKnownEndpoints = new AuthWellKnownEndpoints();
    authWellKnownEndpoints.issuer = environment.oidc.stsServer;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.jwks_uri = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.authorization_endpoint = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/connect/authorize`;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.token_endpoint = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/connect/token`;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.userinfo_endpoint = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/connect/userinfo`;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.end_session_endpoint = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/connect/endsession`;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.check_session_iframe = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/connect/checksession`;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.revocation_endpoint = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/connect/revocation`;
    authWellKnownEndpoints.introspection_endpoint = `${environment.oidc.stsServer}/connect/introspect`;

    this.oidcSecurityService.setupModule(
      openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration,
      authWellKnownEndpoints
    );

  }
}
```

Asp.Net core 2.2 api project start.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:Authority");
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("IdentityServer4Strings:RequireHttpsMetadata");
                    options.ApiName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:ApiName");

                    options.SupportedTokens = IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.SupportedTokens.Jwt;
                    options.ApiSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:STSTSICApisSecuredSecret");
                    options.EnableCaching = true;
                    options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // that's the default
                });


Asp.Net core 2.2 sts project start.cs:

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var identityServer = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>()
            //.AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
            // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources, CORS)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

                // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            })
            .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();


        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();



Api authorize protection decorator (have tried both):
`
        //[Authorize]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
`

Asp.Net core 2.2 sts start.cs:
`
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var identityServer = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
                .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>()
                //.AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources, CORS)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                })
                .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();


            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();
```

Asp.Net core 2.2 sts project IdentityWithAdditionalClaims handler:

```
public IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, SqlDbContext Sql)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
            _context = Sql;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

            var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();
            var tsicCustomClaims = await GetTSICCustomClaims(claims);

            claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "api1"));

            claims.Add(new Claim("regid", tsicCustomClaims.RegId.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("jseg", tsicCustomClaims.JobPath));
            claims.Add(new Claim("jobid", tsicCustomClaims.JobId.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, tsicCustomClaims.RoleName));

            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, tsicCustomClaims.FirstName));
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, tsicCustomClaims.LastName));

            claims.Add(new Claim(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, tsicCustomClaims.EMail));

            context.IssuedClaims = claims;

        }
```

Errors:

```
When accessing the protected api I get from Asp.Net core 2.2 api project:

    [09:29:03 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
    Failed to validate the token.
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44340/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
       at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
       at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
       at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
       at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()

    [09:29:03 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
    BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44340/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.

    [09:29:03 Information] IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
    Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44340/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
```

On startup of the Asp.Net Core 2.2 sts project I get:

```
Seeding database...
Clients already populated
IdentityResources already populated
ApiResources already populated
Done seeding database.

[09:28:09 Information] IdentityServer4.Startup
Starting IdentityServer4 version 2.3.2.0

[09:28:09 Information] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer

[09:28:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication

[09:28:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in

[09:28:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out

[09:28:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge

[09:28:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid

[09:28:10 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.TokenCleanup
Starting grant removal

Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: E:\Projects-STS\TSIC\TSIC.STS
Now listening on: https://localhost:44340
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[09:28:13 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Login Url: /Account/Login

[09:28:13 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl

[09:28:13 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Logout Url: /Account/Logout

[09:28:13 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
ConsentUrl Url: /consent

[09:28:13 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl

[09:28:13 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Error Url: /home/error

[09:28:13 Debug] IdentityServer4.Startup
Error Id Parameter: errorId

[09:28:25 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize

[09:28:25 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint

[09:28:25 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize

[09:28:25 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
Start authorize request

[09:28:25 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
No user present in authorize request

[09:28:25 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Start authorize request protocol validation

[09:28:26 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
angularclient found in database: True

[09:28:26 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
client configuration validation for client angularclient succeeded.

[09:28:27 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found ["openid", "profile", "email", "api1scope"] identity scopes in database

[09:28:27 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found [] API scopes in database

[09:28:27 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found ["openid", "profile", "email", "api1scope"] identity scopes in database

[09:28:27 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found [] API scopes in database
```

I think I'm close here and just need a push in the right direction.

I'm currently focused on the line:

```
[09:28:27 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found [] API scopes in database
```

Thinking this is related to the api project error:

```
IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44340/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
```

This bugs me because the database DOES have an entry in dbo.ApiScopes, from SQL Server:

```
Id  Name    DisplayName Description Required    Emphasize   ShowInDiscoveryDocument ApiResourceId
9   api1    Scope for the api1 ApiResource  NULL    0   0   1   12
```

I'm grateful for any assistance

Comment: Two things I see at the first look. First - the api scope is not an IdentitiyResource. Remove it from there. Second in the Angular module.ts fix the scope to be api1, not api1scope. Then - make sure that `IdentityServer4Strings:Authority` and the value that you are passing to the angular app (`environment.oidc.stsServer`) are the same. That authority `https://localhost:44340/resources` that you get in the error seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

In your angular config you have:

```
 openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.scope = 'openid profile email api1scope';
```

However, it should match one of your valid scopes for the api1:

```
 openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.scope = 'openid profile email api1';
```

Identity Server 4 only adds Api resource as a valid token audience if you request at least one of the scopes that belong to a given api and if your client is allowed that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Vidmantas, thanks for your response, I tried that and same error occurred.  I then got lucky and solved (was a problem with the different audiences indicated in the id token vs the access token, and how the id token aud: could be set by the IdentityServer4 configuration in the Api project startup.cs):

Got it, hope this helps others:

The angular client after logging in is returned:

id token:

```
{
  "nbf": 1550240640,
  "exp": 1550273640,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44340",
  "aud": "https://localhost:44340/resources",
  "client_id": "angularclient",
  "sub": "71765055-647D-432E-AFB6-0F84218D0247",
  "auth_time": 1550240638,
  "idp": "local",
  "regid": "xxxx",
  "jseg": "xxxxx",
  "jobid": "b0984a87-172a-436e-a382-e95de3e1059f",
  "role": "xxxx",
  "given_name": "xxxxx",
  "family_name": "xxxx",
  "email": "xxxx",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

and access token:

```
{
  "nbf": 1550240640,
  "exp": 1550243640,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44340",
  "aud": "angularclient",
  "nonce": "N0.55036966062308791550240634889",
  "iat": 1550240640,
  "at_hash": "yNVxDVHkmEmUvurl7XlzuA",
  "sid": "f54dee03793e7cc202b57f1d6de7622e",
  "sub": "71765055-647D-432E-AFB6-0F84218D0247",
  "auth_time": 1550240638,
  "idp": "local",
  "preferred_username": "TSICSuperUser",
  "name": "xxxx",
  "email": "xxxxx",
  "email_verified": true,
  "regid": "xxxxx",
  "jseg": "xxxxx",
  "jobid": "xxxxxxf",
  "role": "xxxxx",
  "given_name": "xxxx",
  "family_name": "xxxxx",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

NOTE THE DIFFERENT AUDIENCES (aud:)

The Asp.Net Core 2.2 Api Project startup.cs configured IdentityServer4:

```
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:Authority");
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("IdentityServer4Strings:RequireHttpsMetadata");
                    options.ApiName = "api1";

                    options.SupportedTokens = IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.SupportedTokens.Jwt;
                    options.ApiSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:STSTSICApisSecuredSecret");
                    options.EnableCaching = true;
                    options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // that's the default
                });
```

and the Bearer authentication error was:

```
2019-02-14 18:03:15.188 -07:00 [DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
2019-02-14 18:04:04.360 -07:00 [INF] Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44340/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
2019-02-14 18:04:04.430 -07:00 [INF] BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44340/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
2019-02-14 18:04:04.433 -07:00 [INF] Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44340/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
```

The "api1" in error: 
`Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api1'`

references startup.cs

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication
options.ApiName = "api1";
```

Changing the Asp.Net Core 2.2 Api project startup.cs to:

```
            // critical for bearer authentication, the audience of the id token (set by Options.ApiName) is equal to this value
            var idTokenAudience = $"{Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:Authority")}/resources";

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:Authority");
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("IdentityServer4Strings:RequireHttpsMetadata");
                    options.ApiName = idTokenAudience;

                    options.SupportedTokens = IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.SupportedTokens.Jwt;
                    options.ApiSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer4Strings:STSTSICApisSecuredSecret");
                    options.EnableCaching = true;
                    options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // that's the default
                });
```

resolved the issue.

```
2019-02-15 07:45:12.414 -07:00 [INF] Successfully validated the token.
2019-02-15 07:45:12.414 -07:00 [DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.
```